# Making onCreate method look more organized

Tags: android

I have a lot of `Widgets` in my `MainActivity`, and they all have to be initalized. But when I initialize them all in the `OnCreate` method, the `OnCreate` method doesn't look organized anymore. So should I initialize them in another method in my `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely...
Your code must be readable, not everyone think of it..!! :(
Take an example as below...

```js
ublic class ActHome extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    RelativeLayout layoutToBeHidden;
    TextView tvName;
    Button btnOk;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // do the preprocessing here
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
      initialize();
      populate();
    }


    private void initialize() {
      // bind all your view from xml here
        layoutToBeHidden = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutToBeHiddenActHome);
              tvName = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tvNameActHome);
              btnOk = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnOkActHome);
      
      //then set all the listeners etc.
      btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
  
      private void populate() {
      // populate the data here e.g. from database etc.
        // and bind this data to the view etc.
        String name = "android";
        tvName.setText(name);

    }

    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "OK clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use a framework like Butter Knife to reduce code. http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RoboGuice` library to make your `onCreate()` more readable.

`RoboGuice 3` slims down your application code. Less code means fewer opportunities for bugs. It also makes your code easier to follow -- no longer is your code littered with the mechanics of the Android platform, but now it can focus on the actual logic unique to your application.

To give you an idea, take a look at this simple example of a typical Android activity:

```
class AndroidWay extends Activity { 
        TextView name; 
        ImageView thumbnail; 
        LocationManager loc; 
        Drawable icon; 
        String myName; 

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            name      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name); 
            thumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail); 
            loc       = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
            icon      = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon); 
            myName    = getString(R.string.app_name); 
            name.setText( "Hello, " + myName ); 
        } 
    }
```

This example is 19 lines of code. If you're trying to read through `onCreate()`, you have to skip over 5 lines of boilerplate initialization to find the only one that really matters: `name.setText()`. And complex activities can end up with a lot more of this sort of initialization code.

Compare this to the same app, written using `RoboGuice`:

```
@ContentView(R.layout.main)
    class RoboWay extends RoboActivity { 
        @InjectView(R.id.name)             TextView name; 
        @InjectView(R.id.thumbnail)        ImageView thumbnail; 
        @InjectResource(R.drawable.icon)   Drawable icon; 
        @InjectResource(R.string.app_name) String myName; 
        @Inject                            LocationManager loc; 

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            name.setText( "Hello, " + myName ); 
        } 
    }
```

In this example, `onCreate()` is much easier to take in at a glance.

`RoboGuice's` goal is to make your code be about your app, rather than be about all the initialization and lifecycle code you typically have to maintain in Android.

I hope it helps!